# How to add tkinter Scrollbar with Grid?

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar

I am new to Python programming. I started learning the language a few weeks ago. I am creating a "Temperature Converter" application using "tkinter". I am trying to add a scroll bar to the application but unable to do so. Please forgive me if I have not written something correctly. Please do let me know my mistake and I will definitely rectify it. I won't repeat the mistake in the future.

Thank you very much for your time. Following is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.messagebox import showerror
from tkinter import *

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Temperature Converter")
window.geometry('420x400')
window.option_add('*Font', '25')
window.option_add('*Font', 'Tahoma')
window.configure(bg='#f8f8f8')
window.resizable(0, 0)

def fahrenheit_to_celsius():
    fahrenheit = fahrenheit_to_celsius_entry_temperature.get()
    if fahrenheit == '':
        showerror(title='Empty Field Error', message="Field is empty. Please input number.")
    else:
        try:
            celsius = (5 / 9) * (float(fahrenheit) - 32)
            fahrenheit_to_celsius_label_result["text"] = f"{round(celsius, 2)} \N{DEGREE CELSIUS}"
        except:
            showerror(title='Input Error', message="Invalid input. Please input only number.")

fahrenheit_to_celsius_label_heading = tk.Label(text="Fahrenheit to Celsius:", bg='#f8f8f8', fg='Black')
# Create the Fahrenheit entry frame with an Entry widget and label in it
fahrenheit_to_celsius_frame_entry = tk.Frame(master=window)
fahrenheit_to_celsius_entry_temperature = tk.Entry(master=fahrenheit_to_celsius_frame_entry, width=10)
fahrenheit_to_celsius_label_temperature = tk.Label(master=fahrenheit_to_celsius_frame_entry, text="\N{DEGREE FAHRENHEIT}")

def fahrenheit_to_celsius_clear():
    fahrenheit_to_celsius_entry_temperature.delete(0, tk.END)
    fahrenheit_to_celsius_label_result.config(text="\N{DEGREE CELSIUS}")

fahrenheit_to_celsius_button_clear = tk.Button(window, text="Clear", command=fahrenheit_to_celsius_clear, bg='#c82333', fg='White')

fahrenheit_to_celsius_label_heading.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, sticky="w")
fahrenheit_to_celsius_entry_temperature.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="ew")
fahrenheit_to_celsius_label_temperature.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="ew")
fahrenheit_to_celsius_button_clear.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky="w")

fahrenheit_to_celsius_button_convert = tk.Button(master=window, text="Convert", command=fahrenheit_to_celsius, bg='#218838', fg='White')
fahrenheit_to_celsius_label_result = tk.Label(master=window, text="\N{DEGREE CELSIUS}")

fahrenheit_to_celsius_label_heading.grid(row=0, padx=10, pady=10)
fahrenheit_to_celsius_frame_entry.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=12, sticky="ew")
fahrenheit_to_celsius_button_convert.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=0, sticky="ew")
fahrenheit_to_celsius_button_clear.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=(5,0), sticky="ew")
fahrenheit_to_celsius_label_result.grid(row=1, column=3, padx=0, sticky="w")
```

Answer (score 0):

## Adding a scrollbar

Scrollbars can't be added for a tkinter frame, but you can add them for a canvas.

#### procedure

- Put all your widgets in a tkinter canvas
- Configure canvas scrollregion
- Add a scrollbar for the canvas

#### Example

```py
base = tk.Canvas(window)
base.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, side=tk.LEFT, expand=True)
# change scrollregion as changes are made to the canvas
base.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: base.configure(scrollregion=base.bbox(tk.ALL)))

# add scrollbar for the canvas
scroll = tk.Scrollbar(window, command=base.yview)
scroll.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.Y)
base.config(yscrollcommand=scroll.set)

# sample widgets
for i in range(2, 20):
    btn = tk.Button(base, text=f"Button {i}")
    base.create_window(200, i*30, window=btn)
```

For your code, you need to :

- Create a scrollable canvas following above instructions
- Instead of directly using `grid`, use `canvas.create_window(x, y, window)` for each widget

Comment: Hi Billy, thank you very much for your reply. I will try the solution you have suggested. On another note, since I am new to Python programming, looking at the way I have written the code do you think it looks very amateur?

Comment: @AstroGeek If you can do OOP, it would look a lot cleaner :) But since this is a small application, its fine. I found the long variable names kind of troubling though, but its never against python naming conventions.

Comment: Hi, in your code, can I change pack to grid? And how can I change to ?

Comment: @ProMine the canvas and scrollbar are using pack, you can simply change them to grid with appropriate arguments passed [see the docs](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/grid.html). also make sure to use `grid` for all other widgets attached to the same parent